# Visual Studio ASP.Net Application not starting when Target Platform is set to x64 instead of Any Cpu

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have a .Net 5.0/Angular SPA (though the problem is exactly the same when setting the Target framework to .NET Core 3.1) with all dependent assembly projects set to target x64.

When setting the platform target of the application itself to "Any CPU" and starting debugging from Visual Studio, everything starts and works as expected.
When setting the platform target of the application to "x64" though, all I get as an Output from the WebServer is:

```
Usage: dotnet [options]
Usage: dotnet [path-to-application]
Options:
  -h|--help         Display help.
  --info            Display .NET information.
  --list-sdks       Display the installed SDKs.
  --list-runtimes   Display the installed runtimes.
path-to-application:
  The path to an application .dll file to execute.
```

as if the dotnet command line tool was called without any argument.

The version of dotnet that Visual Studio uses seems to be correct and i can start the x64-compiled application manually (by calling `dotnet application-name.dll`) without issue.

I've been fighting with this for three days now and have not gotten an inch closer to a solution.
It would be helpful to see/set the command that Visual Studio is using, when starting the application, but I do not know, how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I manually had to add

```
"commandLineArgs": "run"
```

to launchSettings.json.

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could accept it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.